# Laravel Queue and posting to Facebook

Tags: php, twitter, laravel-5

I'm trying to use larval's queues to post to Facebook , I'm having no luck! my code works fine without using queues, but i need to be able to use the same code with a que.

I'm getting this exception in my failed jobs table:

```
exception 'Exception' with message '[220] Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.' in /home/vagrant/sites/pms/vendor/thujohn/twitter/src/Thujohn/Twitter/Twitter.php:297
```

my initial code to post an image to Facebook looks like this :

```
try {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
    $fb->post('/me/photos', [
         'url' => cloudinary_url("$photorequest"),
         'caption' => $body . $userPage
    ]);
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // continue to next request;
}
```

now with me trying to use a que, I did this in my jobs folder:

```
namespace PMS\Jobs;

use PMS\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk;
use Facebook;
use Session;
use PMS\Photo;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class PostToFBwithImage extends Job implements ShouldQueue {
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public $fb;
    public $token;
    public $photorequest;
    public $userPage;
    public $body;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token, $photorequest, $userPage, $body) {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->photorequest = $photorequest;
        $this->userPage = $userPage;
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {
        try {
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
            $fb->post('/me/photos', [
                'url' => cloudinary_url("$photorequest"),
                'caption' => $body . $userPage
            ]);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // continue to next request;
        }
    }
}
```

and calling this in my controller:

```
$this->dispatch(new PostToFBwithImage($token, $photorequest, $userPage, $body));
```

I know I'm doing something wrong in my PostToFBwithImage class, I just don't know what?

Comment: What queue driver are you using? And in what way is this code not working? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
$fb->post('/me/photos', ['url' => cloudinary_url("$photorequest"),'caption' => $body . $userPage]);
```

be this

```
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($this->token);
$fb->post('/me/photos', ['url' => cloudinary_url($this->photorequest), 'caption' => $this->body . $this->userPage]);
```

?

Also, are you sure you are passing the right values to the constructor when you create the job?